# Converting base 64 into NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, base64

I have this `XML` in `base64` encoding format. I want to convert it into a `NSString` object. How can I do this?

> PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPHN1cnZleSB4bWxuczphYmFw
>   c3VydmV5PSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnNhcC5jb20vYWJhcHN1cnZleSIgeG1sbnM6YmVlPSJodHRwOi8v
>   d3d3LnNhcC5jb20vc3VydmV5L2JlZSIgeG1sbnM6Zm89Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkv
>   WFNML0Zvcm1hdCIgeG1sbnM6aHRtbGI9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cuc2FwLmNvbS9zdXJ2ZXkvaHRtbGIi
>   IHhtbG5zOm91dD0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS9YU0wvT3V0cHV0IiB4bWxuczpzdnk9
>   Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cuc2FwLmNvbS9zdXJ2ZXkvc3Z5IiB4bWxuczp0bXA9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cuc2Fw
>   LmNvbS9zdXJ2ZXkvdG1wIiB4bWxuczp2YWx1ZXM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkvWFNM
>   L1RyYW5zZm9ybVZhbHVlcyIgeG1sbnM6d2ZmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3Lm15c2FwLmNvbS93ZmYvMjAw
>   MSI+PHJhdGluZ2ZhY3Rvcj48cTE+MSA8L3ExPjxpZF8zNmYyN2YwY2UxNDY2MDRlOTIyMzY4Mjcy
>   MWFhMjc5Yj4wIDwvaWRfMzZmMjdmMGNlMTQ2NjA0ZTkyMjM2ODI3MjFhYTI3OWI+PGlkX2Y3YWMx
>   ODM4MDliNjAxNDE4MWVlNGEwNDIyNGYxNTNlPjAgPC9pZF9mN2FjMTgzODA5YjYwMTQxODFlZTRh
>   MDQyMjRmMTUzZT48L3JhdGluZ2ZhY3Rvcj48cmF0aW5nPjxxMT48YTEgcmF0aW5nPSIxICI+aWRf
>   ZTE1ZjhhNjQ5OTY3NDg0ZWI1MzUzZmI5NzIxYWY3NWY8L2ExPjxhMSByYXRpbmc9IjAgIj5pZF9h
>   MzVhMWNmNzNjZmU5MDQ5YTYyMTYwMmFkOTA0NmE0NTwvYTE+PC9xMT48aWRfMzZmMjdmMGNlMTQ2
>   NjA0ZTkyMjM2ODI3MjFhYTI3OWI+PGlkXzgwMTVlNmQ0ZGRmYjkyNDE4ODcxMWIzMGE5MWQzZGU4
>   IE11bHRpcGxlQ2hvaWNlPSJ0cnVlIiByYXRpbmc9IjAgIj5pZF9lMjM0ZDMxM2M3MmRjMzQ2OGMx
>   ODgzNGZhMzBiYzZhNjwvaWRfODAxNWU2ZDRkZGZiOTI0MTg4NzExYjMwYTkxZDNkZTg+PGlkXzgw
>   MTVlNmQ0ZGRmYjkyNDE4ODcxMWIzMGE5MWQzZGU4IE11bHRpcGxlQ2hvaWNlPSJ0cnVlIiByYXRp
>   bmc9IjAgIj5pZF9mYmU2MGUwMGUyMDliNzQyOTk1MjE1NDNiZDZlNzZjNzwvaWRfODAxNWU2ZDRk
>   ZGZiOTI0MTg4NzExYjMwYTkxZDNkZTg+PGlkXzgwMTVlNmQ0ZGRmYjkyNDE4ODcxMWIzMGE5MWQz
>   ZGU4IE11bHRpcGxlQ2hvaWNlPSJ0cnVlIiByYXRpbmc9IjAgIj5pZF80NDc0YTNjOWUwOWFkYjQ3
>   OTRiNDFiN2MyYTAxMzI2OTwvaWRfODAxNWU2ZDRkZGZiOTI0MTg4NzExYjMwYTkxZDNkZTg+PC9p
>   ZF8zNmYyN2YwY2UxNDY2MDRlOTIyMzY4MjcyMWFhMjc5Yj48aWRfZjdhYzE4MzgwOWI2MDE0MTgx
>   ZWU0YTA0MjI0ZjE1M2U+PGlkXzIwYTM4NDliMDAxMGI5NGFhYTRiYTQxMGE0ZDc2NmViIHJhdGlu
>   Zz0iMCAiLz48L2lkX2Y3YWMxODM4MDliNjAxNDE4MWVlNGEwNDIyNGYxNTNlPjwvcmF0aW5nPjxy
>   ZXN1bHQ+PHExPjxhMT5pZF9lMTVmOGE2NDk5Njc0ODRlYjUzNTNmYjk3MjFhZjc1ZjwvYTE+PC9x
>   MT48aWRfMzZmMjdmMGNlMTQ2NjA0ZTkyMjM2ODI3MjFhYTI3OWI+PGlkXzgwMTVlNmQ0ZGRmYjky
>   NDE4ODcxMWIzMGE5MWQzZGU4IE11bHRpcGxlQ2hvaWNlPSJ0cnVlIj4gPC9pZF84MDE1ZTZkNGRk
>   ZmI5MjQxODg3MTFiMzBhOTFkM2RlOD48L2lkXzM2ZjI3ZjBjZTE0NjYwNGU5MjIzNjgyNzIxYWEy
>   NzliPjxpZF9mN2FjMTgzODA5YjYwMTQxODFlZTRhMDQyMjRmMTUzZT48aWRfMjBhMzg0OWIwMDEw
>   Yjk0YWFhNGJhNDEwYTRkNzY2ZWI+PC9pZF8yMGEzODQ5YjAwMTBiOTRhYWE0YmE0MTBhNGQ3NjZl
>   Yj48L2lkX2Y3YWMxODM4MDliNjAxNDE4MWVlNGEwNDIyNGYxNTNlPjwvcmVzdWx0PjxyZXBsYWNl
>   YWJsZXMvPjxzeXN0ZW1wYXJhbWxvY2F0aW9uPmh0dHA6Ly9TdXJ2ZXlSZXAvQ1JNX1NWWV9CU1Bf
>   U1lTVEVNUEFSQU1fSEFSSVRfVEVTVC5YTUw8L3N5c3RlbXBhcmFtbG9jYXRpb24+PGhpZGRlbi8+
>   PHJlYWRPbmx5Lz48bWFuZGF0b3J5Lz48bm9EaXNwbGF5Lz48YWRkSXRlbXMvPjxzY3JpcHQvPjxv
>   bkV2ZW50Lz48L3N1cnZleT4=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second result on Google is this:

```
- (NSString *)base64Encode:(NSString *)plainText
{
  NSData *plainTextData = [plainText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSString *base64String = [plainTextData base64EncodedString];
  return base64String;
}
 
- (NSString *)base64Decode:(NSString *)base64String
{
  NSData *plainTextData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:base64String];
  NSString *plainText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:plainTextData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  return plainText;
}
```

http://agerson.net/base64-encode-and-decode-nsstring-cocoa